# Is it possible to use RestSharp without passing the server address? (or better saying, with relative URL)

Tags: restsharp

I am developing a .NET Core 7 application, using RestSharp to make calls to API inside the same application.

I tried using this contructor:

```
using var client = new RestClient("/api/path/GetById/2");
```

That does not work because I need to add `https://server/`. Is there a way to use it without specifying the server?

Comment: You still need to call a URL. If you call yourself, use `http://localhost:[port]` where `port` is where your Kestrel server responds.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I have finally created an extension method (`public static string? BaseUrl(this HttpRequest req)`) to get the base URL, instead of hardcoding it. But I think this could be an enhancement for the RestSharp component. It could accept a relative URL so that it get the correspoding absolute URL by itself.

Comment: Yeah but how would it get the absolute URL if it doesn't know the root path of the endpoint?